# Custom pch in plot only respects first letter in string

Tags: r, plot

I want the `pch` in the below to show "B -" however it's only showing "B". How do I remedy this?

```
plot(1:3,pch="B -",xlab="",ylab="")
```

Answer (score 4):

Help page of function `par` and argument `pch=` says that `"Either an integer specifying a symbol or a single character to be used as the default in plotting points"`. So only first letter is used as symbol.

You could use function `text()` instead to get all symbols.

```
plot(1:3,type="n",xlab="",ylab="")
text(1:3,"B -")
```